# How to create a function that returns an acronym in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to create an m-file in Matlab that contains the following function:

```
function acr = acronym(phrase)
```

This function should compute and returns the acronym of the phrase as the result of the function; that is, if someone types any phrase in Matlab, this function should return an acronym consisting of the first letter of every word in that phrase. I know that it’s a simple function, but my coding experience is very limited and any help would be appreciated; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This is a great place to use regular expressions. The function `regexp` takes in a string and a regular expression and returns the starting indices for each substring that matches the regular expression. In this case, you want to match any character that starts a word. `\<expr` matches `expr` when it occurs at the start of a word (See the   [documentation for `regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html#f0-42983)). A period matches any character. So the regular expression to match the first character of any word is `\<.`.
Thus,

```
regexp(phrase,'\<.')
```

will return the indices for the first letter of each word in `phrase`. So an acronym function could be:

```
function acr = acronym(phrase)
    ind = regexp(phrase, '\<.');
    acr = upper(phrase(ind));
end
```

Or even just

```
function acr = acronym(phrase)
    acr = upper(phrase(regexp(phrase, '\<.')));
end
```

Comment: Upvoted, I like this answer more than mine! Very neat.

Comment: Thank you for the help and quick replies everyone; these functions work like a charm (especially the last two from AValenzuela). Thanks again for taking the time and effort to help me out; I really appreciate it.

Comment: @OM - if this is the correct solution, please hit the check mark next to the answer to formally accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `textscan` to read a formatted text file as well as a formatted string. Then you just have to keep the first letter of each word:

```
phrase='ceci est une phrase';
words=textscan(phrase,'%s','delimiter',' ');
words=words{:};
letters=cellfun(@(x) x(1),words);
acronym=upper(letters');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function output = acronym( input )
  words_cell = textscan(input,'%s','delimiter',' ');
  words      = words_cell{ : };
  letters    = cellfun(@(x) textscan(x,'%c%*s'), words);
  output     = upper(letters');
end
```

EDIT: Just noticed a very similar answer has already been given!